# HTML downloading and text extraction

Tags: html, linux, text-extraction, download

What would be a good tool, or set of tools, to download a list of URLs and extract only the text content?
Spidering is not required, but control over the download file names, and threading would be a bonus.

The platform is linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`wget`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) `|` [`html2ascii`](http://s23.org/wiki/Html2ascii)

Note: html2ascii can also be called `html2a` or `html2text` (and I wasn't able to find a proper man page on the net for it).

See also: [`lynx`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lynx).

Comment: Does html2text have a strip white-space option, because I couldn't find it

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but you can use awk/sed/perl ... etc to strip whitespace

Comment: Keep an eye out for limitations in the tools.  `lynx`, for example, won't render things like tables.  If `html2ascii` is anything like `pdftotext`, it's able to keep tables in-tact, but it limits output to 80 characters per line.  Given a modestly wide table that would fit comfortably in, say, 150 characters per line, it'll insert new lines and add text vertically and completely destroy readability and/or grepability (if that's a word).

Answer (score 3):

Python [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) allows you to build a [nice extractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380171/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-text-without-tags).

Answer (score 0):

I know that w3m can be used to render an html document and put the text content in a textfile
w3m www.google.com > file.txt  for example.

For the remainder, I'm sure that wget can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the Simple HTML DOM parser for PHP on Sourceforge.  Use it to parse HTML that you have downloaded with CURL.  Each DOM element will have a "plaintext" attribute which should give you only the text.  I was very successful in a lot of applications using this combination for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

PERL (Practical Extracting and Reporting Language) is a scripting language that is excellent for this type of work. http://search.cpan.org/ contains allot of modules that have the required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use wget to download the required html and then run html2text on the output files.