# Using BeautifulSoup to extract text without tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My webpage looks like this:

```html
<p>
  <strong class="offender">YOB:</strong> 1987<br/>
  <strong class="offender">RACE:</strong> WHITE<br/>
  <strong class="offender">GENDER:</strong> FEMALE<br/>
  <strong class="offender">HEIGHT:</strong> 5'05''<br/>
  <strong class="offender">WEIGHT:</strong> 118<br/>
  <strong class="offender">EYE COLOR:</strong> GREEN<br/>
  <strong class="offender">HAIR COLOR:</strong> BROWN<br/>
</p>
```

I want to extract the info for each individual and get `YOB:1987`, `RACE:WHITE`, etc...

What I tried is:

```
subc = soup.find_all('p')
subc1 = subc[1]
subc2 = subc1.find_all('strong')
```

But this gives me only the values of `YOB:`, `RACE:`, etc...

Is there a way that I can get the data in `YOB:1987`, `RACE:WHITE` format?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Just loop through all the `<strong>` tags and use [`next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) to get what you want. Like this:

```
for strong_tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
    print(strong_tag.text, strong_tag.next_sibling)
```

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<p>
  <strong class="offender">YOB:</strong> 1987<br />
  <strong class="offender">RACE:</strong> WHITE<br />
  <strong class="offender">GENDER:</strong> FEMALE<br />
  <strong class="offender">HEIGHT:</strong> 5'05''<br />
  <strong class="offender">WEIGHT:</strong> 118<br />
  <strong class="offender">EYE COLOR:</strong> GREEN<br />
  <strong class="offender">HAIR COLOR:</strong> BROWN<br />
</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for strong_tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
    print(strong_tag.text, strong_tag.next_sibling)
```

This gives you:

```
YOB:  1987
RACE:  WHITE
GENDER:  FEMALE
HEIGHT:  5'05''
WEIGHT:  118
EYE COLOR:  GREEN
HAIR COLOR:  BROWN
```

Answer (score 45):

I think you can get it using `subc1.text`.

```
>>> html = """
<p>
    <strong class="offender">YOB:</strong> 1987<br />
    <strong class="offender">RACE:</strong> WHITE<br />
    <strong class="offender">GENDER:</strong> FEMALE<br />
    <strong class="offender">HEIGHT:</strong> 5'05''<br />
    <strong class="offender">WEIGHT:</strong> 118<br />
    <strong class="offender">EYE COLOR:</strong> GREEN<br />
    <strong class="offender">HAIR COLOR:</strong> BROWN<br />
</p>
"""
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print soup.text


YOB: 1987
RACE: WHITE
GENDER: FEMALE
HEIGHT: 5'05''
WEIGHT: 118
EYE COLOR: GREEN
HAIR COLOR: BROWN
```

Or if you want to *explore* it, you can use `.contents` :

```
>>> p = soup.find('p')
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(p.contents)
[u'\n',
 <strong class="offender">YOB:</strong>,
 u' 1987',
 <br/>,
 u'\n',
 <strong class="offender">RACE:</strong>,
 u' WHITE',
 <br/>,
 u'\n',
 <strong class="offender">GENDER:</strong>,
 u' FEMALE',
 <br/>,
 u'\n',
 <strong class="offender">HEIGHT:</strong>,
 u" 5'05''",
 <br/>,
 u'\n',
 <strong class="offender">WEIGHT:</strong>,
 u' 118',
 <br/>,
 u'\n',
 <strong class="offender">EYE COLOR:</strong>,
 u' GREEN',
 <br/>,
 u'\n',
 <strong class="offender">HAIR COLOR:</strong>,
 u' BROWN',
 <br/>,
 u'\n']
```

and filter out the necessary items from the list:

```
>>> data = dict(zip([x.text for x in p.contents[1::4]], [x.strip() for x in p.contents[2::4]]))
>>> pprint(data)
{u'EYE COLOR:': u'GREEN',
 u'GENDER:': u'FEMALE',
 u'HAIR COLOR:': u'BROWN',
 u'HEIGHT:': u"5'05''",
 u'RACE:': u'WHITE',
 u'WEIGHT:': u'118',
 u'YOB:': u'1987'}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this indside findall for loop:

```
item_price = item.find('span', attrs={'class':'s-item__price'}).text
```

it extracts only text and assigs it to "item_pice"

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve this with `.strip()` in [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

Input:

```py
html = """\
<p>
  <strong class="offender">YOB:</strong> 1987<br />
  <strong class="offender">RACE:</strong> WHITE<br />
  <strong class="offender">GENDER:</strong> FEMALE<br />
  <strong class="offender">HEIGHT:</strong> 5'05''<br />
  <strong class="offender">WEIGHT:</strong> 118<br />
  <strong class="offender">EYE COLOR:</strong> GREEN<br />
  <strong class="offender">HAIR COLOR:</strong> BROWN<br />
</p>
"""
```

Code:

```py
soup = Soup(html)
text = soup.find("p").strip(whitespace=False) # to keep \n characters intact
lines = [
    line.strip()
    for line in text.split("\n")
    if line != ""
]
data = dict([line.split(": ") for line in lines])
```

Output:

```py
print(data)
# {'YOB': '1987',
#  'RACE': 'WHITE',
#  'GENDER': 'FEMALE',
#  'HEIGHT': "5'05''",
#  'WEIGHT': '118',
#  'EYE COLOR': 'GREEN',
#  'HAIR COLOR': 'BROWN'}
```