# How to extract the text inside a tag with BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Supposing I have an html string like this:

```
<html>
    <div id="d1">
        Text 1
    </div>
    <div id="d2">
        Text 2
        <a href="http://my.url/">a url</a>
        Text 2 continue
    </div>
    <div id="d3">
        Text 3
    </div>
</html>
```

I want to extract the content of `d2` that is **NOT** wrapped by other tags, skipping `a url`. In other words I want to get such result:

```
Text 2
Text 2 continue
```

Is there a way to do it with BeautifulSoup?

I tried this, but it is not correct:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
s = soup.find(id='d2').text
print(s)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using BeautifulSoup to extract text without tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380171/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-text-without-tags)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with `.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
div_test="""
<html>
    <div id="d1">
        Text 1
    </div>
    <div id="d2">
        Text 2
        <a href="http://my.url/">a url</a>
        Text 2 continue
    </div>
    <div id="d3">
        Text 3
    </div>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(div_test, 'lxml')
s = soup.find(id='d2').find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
print(s)
print([e.strip() for e in s]) #remove space
```

it will return a `list` with only `text`:

```
[u'\n        Text 2\n        ', u'\n        Text 2 continue\n    ']
[u'Text 2', u'Text 2 continue']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get only the `NavigableString` objects with a simple list comprehension.

```
tag = soup.find(id='d2')
s = ''.join(e for e in tag if type(e) is bs4.element.NavigableString)
```

Alternatively you can use the `decompose` method to delete all the child nodes, then get all the remaining items with `text` .

```
tag = soup.find(id='d2')
for e in tag.find_all() : 
    e.decompose()
s = tag.text
```