# Getting views+shares from Facebook url

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to get the views and shares from a FB url (https://www.facebook.com//peopleareawesome/videos/1393626100686564) but I am stuck. I am using Beautifulsoup in Python3 and I am able to parse the page but I can't filter out the info I need. Below is my code and I would really appreciate any help. All I need is to write a function that takes in an URL and outputs number of shares and views.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.facebook.com/peopleareawesome/videos/1393626100686564/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html5lib")        
for line in soup.findAll('script'): # should it be div?     
    print (line) #this is where I expect to get views and shares info
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see where you are attempting to return the shares and views of the video. Quite simply, you'll need to inspect the elements on the page and extract the specific information from the `BeautifulSoup` object. There is plenty of documentation online for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380171/using-beautifulsoup-extract-text-without-tags

Comment: What about now? I have been struggling with how BS label its parsed data. I am able to get the chunk of div or script that contains the views/shares lines but I can't reach to those lines.

Comment: The number of shares, for example, is contained in an `<a>` tag with the class `UFIShareLink`. So, in BS4 you will need to find that tag and extract the text. There are plenty of places you can find out how to do this online and plenty of tutorials.

Comment: Scraping Facebook pages is against their ToS. If anything, you should be using their API.

Comment: All I need is views and shares of a FB video. If they don't want people to scrap their pages for that info, maybe they should make it available in their API which they don't.