# HTML text extraction

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a list as below that came from Beautiful Soup.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
area = soup.select("td strong")
```

For example

```
area=[
<strong><span style="font-size:1.4em;">120 Beats Per Minute (15)</span><br/><br/>Cinema</strong>, 
<strong><span style="font-size:1.4em;">A Little Night Music</span><br/><br/>Theatre</strong>, 
<strong><span style="font-size:1.4em;">A Wrinkle in Time (PG)</span><br/><br/>Cinema</strong>
]
```

I need to get rid of text except for Cinema, Theatre.

I've come up with the expression below but I can't apply this to the list

```
x[x.find('<br/><br/>')+10:].replace('</strong>','')
```

Any ideas how I can apply this expression to extract data from the list to make a new list?  I've tried this :

```
clean_area=[]
for x in area:
   clean_area.append(x[x.find('<br/><br/>')+10:].replace('</strong>',''))
```

But I get this error :
     TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Well, that error is saying `x.find('<br/><br/>')` didn't find anything

Comment: If I manually copy/paste one of the list elements into a string x my expression works.

Comment: Maybe one of the other area strings doesn't have two breaks?

Comment: I would suggest actually parsing the text rather than looking for subtags. https://stackoverflow.com/q/23380171/2308683

Comment: I can't as the text gets merged - I need dump the tags as well as text into a normal list so I can manipulate the data.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was answering your first post about an hour ago but you removed it.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but here is what I came up with:

```
text = [
"""<strong><span style="font-size:1.4em;">120 Beats Per Minute (15)</span><br/><br/>Cinema</strong>""", 
"""<strong><span style="font-size:1.4em;">A Little Night Music</span><br/><br/>Theatre</strong>""", 
"""<strong><span style="font-size:1.4em;">A Wrinkle in Time (PG)</span><br/><br/>Cinema</strong>"""
]

text = ''.join(text) #Converting list of strings to one string

start = "<br/><br/>" #Start indication
end = "</" #End indication

clean_area = []

index = 0
while index < len(text):
    index = text.find(start, index)
    if index == -1:
        break
    clean_area.append(text[index+len(start):text.find(end, index)])
    index += len(start)

print(clean_area)
```

Comment: The text I have is in a 1-dim list with each element corresponding to text string in your answer.   How can I loop through the list with your code?

Comment: You can make the list into a string by doing area = ''.join(area). I'll edit my answer to show it with your example

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is `decompose` this will take out any tags you do not want.

In this case it is the `span`

so

```
for x in soup.findAll("span"):
    x.decompose()

print(soup.text)
```

returns

`Cinema, Theatre`

Answer (score 0):

I could only get this working with 2 passes.  I'm sure it's not the best way but it at least works.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "html.parser")

for x in soup.findAll("span"):
    x.decompose()

area = soup.select("td strong")

a = str(area)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(a)



tr = []
for tag in soup2.find_all(True):
    tr.append(tag.text)


clean_area = [] 
for i in tr[::3]:
    clean_area.append(i)
```