# How to automate scraping wikipedia info box specifically and print the data using python for any wiki page?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

My task is to automate printing the wikipedia infobox data.As an example, I am scraping the Star Trek wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek) and extract infobox section from the right hand side and print them **row by row** on screen using python. I specifically want the info box. So far I have done this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
# specify the url
urlpage =  'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek'
# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)
# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
# find results within table
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'infobox vevent'})
results = table.find_all('tr')
print(type(results))
print('Number of results', len(results))
print(results)
```

This gives me everything from the info box. A snippet is shown below:

```
[<tr><th class="summary" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;font- 
size:125%;font-weight:bold;font-style: italic; background: lavender;"> 
<i>Star Trek</i></th></tr>, <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<a class="image" href="/wiki/File:Star_Trek_TOS_logo.svg"><img alt="Star 
Trek TOS logo.svg" data-file-height="132" data-file-width="560" height="59"
```

I want to extract the data only and print it on screen. So What i want is:

```
Created by  Gene Roddenberry
Original work   Star Trek: The Original Series
Print publications
Book(s) 
List of reference books
List of technical manuals
Novel(s)    List of novels
Comics  List of comics
Magazine(s) 
Star Trek: The Magazine
Star Trek Magazine
```

And so on till the end of the infobox. So basically a way of printing every row of the infobox data so I can automate it for any wiki page? (The class of infobox table of all wiki pages is 'infobox vevent' as shown in the code)

Comment: What is wrong with parsing the content of the info box as well?

Answer (score 0):

This page should help you to parse your html as a simple string without the html tags [Using BeautifulSoup Extract Text without Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380171/using-beautifulsoup-extract-text-without-tags)

This is a code from that page, it belongs to @0605002

```
>>> html = """
<p>
    <strong class="offender">YOB:</strong> 1987<br />
    <strong class="offender">RACE:</strong> WHITE<br />
    <strong class="offender">GENDER:</strong> FEMALE<br />
    <strong class="offender">HEIGHT:</strong> 5'05''<br />
    <strong class="offender">WEIGHT:</strong> 118<br />
    <strong class="offender">EYE COLOR:</strong> GREEN<br />
    <strong class="offender">HAIR COLOR:</strong> BROWN<br />
</p>
"""
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print soup.text


YOB: 1987
RACE: WHITE
GENDER: FEMALE
HEIGHT: 5'05''
WEIGHT: 118
EYE COLOR: GREEN
HAIR COLOR: BROWN
```

Answer (score 0):

By using beautifulsoup,you need to reformat the data as you want. use `fresult =  [e.text for e in result]` to get each result

If you want to read a table on html you can try some code like this,though this is using pandas.

```
import pandas
urlpage =  'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek'
data = pandas.read_html(urlpage)[0]
null = data.isnull()

for x in range(len(data)):
    first = data.iloc[x][0]
    second = data.iloc[x][1] if not null.iloc[x][1] else ""
    print(first,second,"\n")
```