# Get numerical value of a html tag in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

I want to scrape yahoo! finance and get the numerical value for "Net Assets" of any security:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
sii = "AGG"
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s?p=%s&.tsrc=fin-srch" % (sii, sii)
response = requests.get(url) # send request to yahoo!
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

When I do this:

```
soup.find_all("span")
```

It returns:

```
 [ <span data-reactid="53">Net Assets</span>,
   <span class="Trsdu(0.3s) " data-reactid="55">72.72B</span>,]
```

My question is , how do I access the numerical value inside the last tag , eg. 72.72B ?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using BeautifulSoup to extract text without tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380171/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-text-without-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_all()` returns a list, so if you want the information inside the last tag, you can do this:

```
result = soup.find_all("span") 
myvalue = result[-1].text
```

If it's less about getting the last item and rather about getting the text from the `span` that matches a certain value, you can do the same thing with and key/value condition.

```
result = soup.find_all("span", {"data-reactid":"82"}) 
myvalue = result[0].text
```

Comment: thanks ! the .text is what I was looking for . I would use the data-reactid but in this case it changes between securiteis