# cant extract text from price-save-percent container from newegg.com

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to get the savings price from newegg.com but cant seem split or extract the text

so far i have

```
save_percent = container.findAll('span', {'class': 'price-save-percent'})
```

which gets me

```
[<span class="price-save-percent">8%</span>]
```

what i need is just the 8%.
what iv tried so far is converting the output into a list and indexing it but it doesn't get stored correctly or the way i need it to. iv tried converting it to a string and using replace and translate to remove characters but for some reason thats not doing anything. Im stuck on what to try next, any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT.

```
import bs4 
from urllib.request import urlopen as urlo
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
page = '1'
count = 0
my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Desktop-Graphics-Cards/SubCategory/ID-48/Page-'+ page +'?Tid=7709'

    #opening connection
uClient = urlo(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    # Grabs Graphics card products contianers
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"item-container"})

filename = 'graphics_cards.csv'
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "brand, product_name, shipping, price\n"
f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    item_brand = container.findAll("a", {"class": "item-brand"})    
    brand = item_brand[0].img["title"]

    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class": "item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text


    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class": "price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

    price_container = container.findAll("li", {"class", "price-current"})
    price_list = price_container[0].text.split()
    price = price_list[0]

    save_percent = container.findAll('span', {'class': 'price-save-percent'})
    percent_saved = save_percent
    psave = percent_saved[0].text

    print("brand " + brand)
    print("product name " + product_name)
    print("shipping " + shipping)
    print('price' + price)
    print('percent_saved' + psave)

    f.write(brand + ',' + product_name.replace(',', '|') + ',' + shipping + ',' + psave + ',"' + price + '"\n')
```

Comment: `save_percent[0].text` - if you have it as list...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using BeautifulSoup to extract text without tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380171/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-text-without-tags)

Comment: @PatrickArtner Should than not be .text()?

Comment: It's odd then that Inspect element/copy Xpath in Google adds the parentheses then.

Comment: Often websites know when they are being crawled, because of  things like user agent - or more sophisticated mechanisms. Maybe its down to that.. The html being crawled is not the same as what you see in Chrome directly.

Comment: I am using BeautifulSoup. I have tried .text but i just get IndexError: list index out of range. would writing the output to a csv file change anything?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? It's unclear how you got these results.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i finally got it to work after a few days. i think my issue was that i was getting an error because most of the graphics cards containers were empty.

all i did was add an if statement to account for that

here's my solution

```
save_percent = container.findAll('span', {'class': 'price-save-percent'})
    percent_saved = save_percent

try:
    psave = percent_saved[0].text
except IndexError:
    psave = 'null'
if psave == '':
   psave = 'null'
```

now if works like its supposed to. hope this helps someone out there