# BeautifulSoup text extraction breaks text in more lines in case of anchor tags - Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I want to scrape all meaningful textual content from HTML pages of different websites to save it into a list.

I am using the following code to extract the text:

```
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all(text=True)

for t in text:
    output_list.append(t)
```

It works well with the exception of paragraphs that contain  tags inside. In these cases, the paragraph is split into 3 different list elements. e.g.

```
Data science is an < a href="/wiki/Inter-disciplinary" title="Inter-disciplinary">inter-disciplinary</a> field that uses scientific methods
```

Becomes:

```
0 Data science is an
1 inter-disciplinary
2 field that uses scientific methods
```

However, I would get something like this:

```
0 Data science is an inter-disciplinary field that uses scientific methods
```

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: This approach might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380171/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-text-without-tags

Comment: It cant be formed into the 3 lines as u suggest, this is because the 2nd and 3rd arent separated by any tags so it can only be made as : `1. Data science is an`, `2. inter-disciplinary field that uses scientific methods`. You can do so by the way your `find_all()` method extracts the text

Comment: Please share the URL